# Getting free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped) while using python interpreter in ubunutu

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, readlines

I was facing [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell) issue in my **[ubuntu-22.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-22.04)** and I solved that issue by installing ***[`readline`](https://pypi.org/project/readline/)*** package but after that I'm facing following issue

> ```
> Python 3.8.13 (default, May 21 2022, 14:21:55) 
> [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> 2 + 2
> free(): invalid pointer
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

I've checked this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363390/14457833) it says

> *There is a known issue with importing both **open3d** and **PyTorch**. The
> cause is unknown.*

but in my case it's not related to **PyTorch** or **open3d** on same question another [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56347245/14457833) says

> *This is not a problem in your **Python** code. It is a bug in **PyTorch**
> (probably) or in **Python** itself (unlikely, but possible).*

at this point I'm confuse how to solve this issue. Do I have to rebuild python ? ***(current python was build using make)***

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you provide more info about your setup. I'm sure the key has something to do with how you built Python, but just (current python was build using make) doesn't give me enough info to replicate your setup. I assume the builtin OS packaged version of python doesn't do this?

Comment: Hello @MattBlaha here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112006/14457833) I followed to build python

Comment: Hello @SunderamDubey No, worries issue was fixed after restarting my system (:

Comment: Ahh! That's what happen to people in programming, I also faced this thing with javascript modules sometimes anyway.